# xamarin android async method not working

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous, xamarin, async-await

I have a static method on my portable class

```
async public static Task<JSONObject> CheckToken(string token)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
   {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("tag", "checkToken"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("token", token)
    });
    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://10.0.0.6:888/api.php",     formContent);
    string res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return new JSONObject(res);
}
```

Main Activity Code

```
protected override async void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    FacebookSdk.SdkInitialize(this);

    LoginManager.Instance.LogOut();

    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    var tracker = new myTokenT(this);
    tracker.StartTracking();

    ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    var token = prefs.GetString("token","notoken");
    var res = await Client.CheckToken(token); // stop here
......
}
```

when it reaches

```
 var response = await client.PostAsync("http://10.0.0.6:888/api.php",     formContent);
```

getting exception System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.

it stops.. like I am waiting 3 minutes and then I get the exception,
funny thing is that it worked before! I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Is http://10.0.0.6:888/api.php reachable from the device or emulator you are testing it on?

Comment: yes its the internal ip of my computer I also checked sent the requests manually and is working fine

Comment: Can you use the device/emulator's browser to access "http://10.0.0.6" ? Using adb:  `adb shell ping 10.0.0.6` to test access from within the device/emulator to your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *Assuming* ICMP is enabled on that server, use Android's `adb` to test access from within the device/emulator to that server:

  adb shell ping 10.0.0.6
- *Assuming* you have some type of open access test/status web page on that web server, can you browse that server from the device/emulator's web browser?